# add Related Media to Dynamic Content in Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity, dynamic-content

Today, I get the error " Object must implement IConvertible." when I try to Add Related Media item to Dynamic Content, I have Ajax to Upload Image to Sitefinity Administrator. this is the code.

```
var doctorType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType(ConstUtil.DoctorType);
var liveItem = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItem(doctorType, Authentication.Id);

dynamicModuleManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;

var masterItem = dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.GetMaster(liveItem) as DynamicContent;
var cultureName = CurrentCulture;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);

var draftItem = dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.CheckOut(masterItem) as DynamicContent;

if (draftItem == null)
{
                    return new HttpResponseMessage
          {
                Content = new JsonContent(new { Result = false })
          };
 }

var newImage = UploadImage(model);

if (newImage != null)
{
           //var contentLink = new ContentLink(newImage.Parent.Id, newImage.Id);
            //draftItem.SetValue("photo" , NewImage);

}
```

// Now we need to check in, so the changes apply

```
var checkInDoctorItem = dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.CheckIn(draftItem);

dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.Publish(checkInDoctorItem);
dynamicModuleManager.SaveChanges();
```

I Try to fix this error by two ways

```
1) draftItem.AddImage("photo", newImage); It still get same Error

2) draftItem.CreateRelation(newImage, CustomFieldName.DoctorProfilePhoto);
```

It not get an error, but it cannot save the new Image to the target.

So I Use Sitefinity 7.0, please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrangled with a similar issue.  Steps to perform:

1 -  Get the image uploaded to a library. This article has several valid examples that will help get the image uploaded correctly: http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/general-discussions-/add-images-to-the-library-programatically

2 -  Call the draftItem.CreateRelation(image, fieldName) method like you have above

3 -  Publish

```
dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.Publish(checkInDoctorItem);
draftItem.SetWorkflowStatus(dynamicModuleManager.Provider.ApplicationName, "Published");
dynamicModuleManager.SaveChanges();
```